# Sujeto de la oración "Está oscureciendo temprano"

Tags: gramática

Tengo una duda con esta tarea de mi hijo. La oración es muy simple:

> Está oscureciendo temprano.

Pienso que puede ser una oración impersonal sin sujeto, como en "*Llueve fuerte*", pero semánticamente "siento" que el que oscurece es el *día*.

¿Cómo se analiza este tipo de oraciones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, en principio, [*oscurecer*](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=oscurecer) está registrado en el DRAE tanto como transitivo (cuando el sujeto hace otra cosa más oscura), pronominal (cuando el sujeto se convierte más oscuro) e impersonal.

Si fuese que el día estuviera poniéndose más oscuro, tendría que ser pronominal: El día está oscureciéndose.

Ya que no es pronominal, la interpretación impersonal es la más razonable a menos que interpretemos toda la frase con sujeto *y* objeto omitidos (muy improbable, opino yo), queriendo decir que el día en general oscurece otras cosas.

Comment: OK. Después pensé se aclaraba la situación usando el plural _Los días están oscureciendo_. Pero tienes razón, es posible pero rebuscado, nadie piensa en eso cuando dice que _está oscureciendo_. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.